# does the nexus will fetch package from pypi when the version did not exists in nexus

Tags: python, nexus

When I am using this command to install python package from the local nexus proxy:

```
$ pip install --trusted-host 192.168.50.90 -i http://192.168.50.90:8092/repository/pypi-proxy/simple rdpywheel==0.1.27         ‹ruby-2.7.2›
Looking in indexes: http://192.168.50.90:8092/repository/pypi-proxy/simple
User for 192.168.50.90:8092: admin
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rdpywheel==0.1.27 (from versions: 0.0.1, 0.1, 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3, 0.1.4, 0.1.5, 0.1.6, 0.1.7, 0.1.8, 0.1.9, 0.1.10, 0.1.11, 0.1.12, 0.1.13, 0.1.14, 0.1.15, 0.1.16, 0.1.17, 0.1.18, 0.1.19, 0.1.20, 0.1.21, 0.1.22, 0.1.23, 0.1.24, 0.1.25, 0.1.26)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for rdpywheel==0.1.27
(venv) (base)
```

actually the version 0.1.27 was exists in the pypi official repo. why could not install this version of package from the nexus repo? the nexus will fetch the newest package when not exists in local repo? the nexus version is `OSS 3.51.0-01`. The nexus configuration url is :https://pypi.org.